# Reduce es6 изменить структуру объекта, тройное условие

Tags: javascript, объекты, filter, chart.js, map-reduce

Есть объект отфильтрованный по датам, где индекс элемента массива "names" равен индексу элемента массива "weld_length_for_day", т.е. Алексей никашкин - 9114, Алексей морозов - 1013, Алексей Морозов 6422 и т.д.

```
{
  "05.08.2019": {
    "names": [
      "Алексей Никашкин",
      "Алексей Морозов",
      "Алексей Морозов",
      "Алексей Морозов",
      "Алексей Никашкин",
      "Алексей Морозов",
      "Алексей Морозов"
    ],
    "weld_length_for_day": [
      9114,
      1013,
      6422,
      6260,
      0,
      1519,
      4088
    ]
  },
  "06.08.2019": {
    "names": [
      "Алексей Никашкин",
      "Алексей Никашкин",
      "Алексей Никашкин",
      "Алексей Морозов",
      "Алексей Морозов",
      "Алексей Морозов"
    ],
    "weld_length_for_day": [
      6330,
      8835,
      5728,
      8142,
      8940,
      3544
    ]
  }
}
```

Хотелось бы получить промежуточный объект вида

```
var prepare_obj = {
    "05.08.2019": {
      "Алексей Никашкин": {
        "name" : "Алексей Никашкин",
        "sum_weld_length_for_day" : 9114, //9114+0=9114
       },
      "Алексей Морозов": {
        "name" : "Алексей Морозов",
        "sum_weld_length_for_day" : 19302, //1013+6422+6260+1519+4088 = 19302
      }
    },
    "06.08.2019": {
      "Алексей Никашкин": {
        "name" : "Алексей Никашкин",
        "sum_weld_length_for_day" : 20893, //6330+8835+5728=20839
      },
      "Алексей Морозов": {
        "name" : "Алексей Морозов",
        "sum_weld_length_for_day" : 20626, //8142+8940+3544=20626
      }
    }
```

Чтобы потом сформировать объект в котором массив "arr_date_range_weld_length" в котором по логике индексный элемент будет являться датой в прежнем объекте

```
var finally_obj = {
  "Алексей Никашкин": {
    "name" : "Алексей Никашкин",
    "arr_date_range_weld_length" : [9114, 20893], //9114(05.08.2019), 20893(06.08.2019)
  },
  "Алексей Морозов": {
    "name" : "Алексей Морозов",
    "arr_date_range_weld_length" : [19302, 20626], //19302(05.08.2019), 20626(06.08.2019)
  }
}
console.log(finally_obj);
```

Прошу помощи с reduce.

Comment: дак вам этот промежуточный то в итоге зачем-то нужен?

Comment: Суть в том что у меня диапазон дат. Допустим с 03.08.2019 по 31.08.2019.
В каждой дате по несколько сотрудников, со значением длинны шва. Также может быть несколько одинаковых дат, например `[
 {
    DATE: "01.04.2019",   
    NAME: "Алексей Морозов",
    PRODUCT: "BM-100-4D (до 100 кВт, подкл. котла G 1¼″, 3+1 контура G 1″)",
    SUM_WELD_LENGTH: 12213,
 },
 { 
    DATE: "01.04.2019",
    NAME: "Алексей Морозов",
    PRODUCT: "NG-32 (1¼&quot;, 125 мм, прямая группа)",
    SUM_WELD_LENGTH: 0,
 }
]`
Не могу по другому представить, поэтому первый массив по датам.

Comment: я про промежуточный спрашивал, а  не про первый. И кстати, ES6 у вас указан как все версии до него, включительно, и он и более новые?

Comment: Все версии до него включительно, желательно

Comment: а как вы этот первый объект вообще получаете? какое-то у меня подозрение, что все это дело тянется из базы данных, и можно изначально вытащить посчитанные суммы, а не ковыряться сначала на бэкенде, а потом в js.

Comment: @teran
К сожалению в таком виде нужно для таблицы с фильтрами и сортировкой Tabulator.js.
А уже при фильтрации этой таблицы данные летят в chart.js чтобы построить график.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  "05.08.2019": {
names: [
  "Алексей Никашкин",
  "Алексей Морозов",
  "Алексей Морозов",
  "Алексей Морозов",
  "Алексей Никашкин",
  "Алексей Морозов",
  "Алексей Морозов",
  "James Bond"
],
weld_length_for_day: [9114, 1013, 6422, 6260, 0, 1519, 4088, 666]
  },
  "06.08.2019": {
names: [
  "Алексей Никашкин",
  "Алексей Никашкин",
  "Алексей Никашкин",
  "Алексей Морозов",
  "Алексей Морозов",
  "Алексей Морозов"
],
weld_length_for_day: [6330, 8835, 5728, 8142, 8940, 3544]
  }
};

function getAllNames(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((n, date) => {
return o[date].names.reduce((names, name) => {
  if (names.indexOf(name) === -1) names.push(name);
  return names;
}, n);
  }, []);
}

let res = {};
let finally_obj = {};
let allNames = getAllNames(obj);

console.log(allNames);

for (key in obj) {
  const day = obj[key];
  const { names, weld_length_for_day } = day;
  res[key] = names.reduce((nextNames, currentName, index) => {
if (nextNames[currentName]) {
  nextNames[currentName] =
    nextNames[currentName] + weld_length_for_day[index];
} else {
  nextNames[currentName] = weld_length_for_day[index];
}
return nextNames;
  }, {});

  // Добавляем 0 для имен, которые не встречаются
  for (index in allNames) {
if (!res[key][allNames[index]]) {
  res[key][allNames[index]] = 0;
}
  }

  for (name in res[key]) {
res[key][name] = {
  name,
  weld_length_for_day: res[key][name]
};
if (finally_obj[name]) {
  finally_obj[name].weld_length_for_day.push(
    res[key][name].weld_length_for_day
  );
} else {
  finally_obj[name] = {
    name,
    weld_length_for_day: [res[key][name].weld_length_for_day]
  };
}
  }
}
console.log("===++++++++====");
console.log(res);
console.log("===++++++++====");
console.log(finally_obj);
```

Comment: Благодарю. А есть возможность чтобы weld_length_for_day (arr_date_range), был одинаковый у всех сотрудников? 
У одного сотрудника может быть 3 значения в финальном массиве weld_length_for_day (arr_date_range), а у другого 2. 

- Можно ли в начале заполнить нулями массив weld_length_for_day  на длину максимального. (Для этого есть отдельный массив дат)
- А затем заполнить массив weld_length_for_day значениями, индексы которых будут равны индексам в отдельном массиве дат.
Чтобы сопоставить для графиков даты `"data": [ 13664, 19302, 20626, 35990, 30866, 19568, 2668, 47430, 35299 ]`

Comment: это для промежуточной структуры?

Comment: кажется я понял

Comment: "хозяйка! принимай работу"

Comment: Это шедевр!)
Огромное спасибо!

Comment: ну такое... прочитать очень трудно :)